# Not showing last/my edit in revisions list

Tags: bug, ios-app, revisions-list

Steps to reproduce:

1. Look at the revision list for a question.
2. Edit that question and submit.
3. Observer that question body is updated.
4. Go to revisions again.
5. Can't see my edit in revisions.

---

- App Version: 1.6.0.10
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.0.2 (Build 14A456)

Comment: It does here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/34ZLG.png

Comment: @PatrickHofman may be the reason is iPad version of app? Can u test it? I don't have iPhone.

Comment: It should be the same app and I don't have a iPad near me now. Will take a look later if I have some time.

Comment: Does this happen every time? On every post? Or was it just a specific edit? Did you make another edit not long previously (I think 5 minutes, which would roll the edits in to one revision)?

Comment: @Cai every time just after edit happen. Now I can see my last edit (after your comment, or after 10 minutes delay possible).

Comment: There can be some delay indeed since it has to sync back the changes from the main database.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Why would not to update revisions after question has been edited?

Comment: Because only the main database can be changed. The API works on the read-only database. Edits are posted to the main database and eventually synced back.

Comment: Added a step necessary for 100% repro.  The problem is that the old revision list is getting cached before you edit it so it's not reflecting the new data.  I'll add a cache breaker the next time I do API work.